# Password encryption with liquibase maven plugin

Tags: maven, liquibase, password-encryption

Currently  i am using liquibase maven plugin for database changes and my database credentials are in plain text format in .m2/settings.xml.

By using mavens password encryption, i want to encrypt database passwords(currently passwords are in plain text format in .m2/settings.xml) so that i can share my settings.xml with other developers.

Maven Password encryption works fine with cargo plugin, but not working with liquibase plugin.

Can some help me out , how to solve this issue.

Comment: Perhaps https://forum.liquibase.org/#topic/49382000000278005 is your post...

Comment: yes, i am looking answer for similar question, thanks raghuram for finding it.

Comment: So this question is obsolete now? Could you delete it in case?

Answer (score 0):

creds to https://apexplained.wordpress.com/2015/08/08/password-encryption-in-the-liquibase-maven-plugin/

server.xml file contents:

```
<settings>
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>your_entry</id>
            <username>username</username>
            <password>encrypted_password</password>
```

pom.xml file contents:

```
<build>
...
        <extensions>
            <extension>
                <groupId>com.github.shyiko.servers-maven-extension</groupId>
                <artifactId>servers-maven-extension</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.1</version>
            </extension>
        </extensions>
...
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${liquibase.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
                    <url>${db.pg.connection.url}</url>
                    <username>${db.pg.userId}</username>
                    <password>${settings.servers.your_entry.password}</password>
```